# Basic Auth for EnvelopeDefinition:EventNotification API types

Tags: rest, basic-authentication, webhooks, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign REST API to send documents and we are trying to take advantage of the webhook capabilities.

Our problem is that we have basic auth set up on our webhook listener which it doesn't appear is supported in the REST API. I am enquiring whether or not this is an accurate understanding. I know it is possible on the Connect product, which the basic auth can be set up via the portal, however I am looking specifically for API REST calls.

How can I secure the EventNotification event?

Many thanks,
Mitch.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, according to [docusign offical post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-connect-basic-authentication-support/):

> Individual Envelope Connect configurations created with the eventNotifications API option do not support Basic Authentication at this time.

---

**A WORKAROUND SOLUTION:**

Docusign has an official blog post to answer this question. [Securing Your Connect Webhook Listener](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/)

For us, we use the **Use a Pre-shared Secret** method to secure our webhook. We are using the python sdk. During the process we create the EventNotification, we add a secret parameter to the webhook listener url. When the docusign post the request to your listener server, it will include the secret. You could check the parameter to make sure the request is valid.

```
event_notification = EventNotification()
event_notification.url ='your webhook_url' + '?secret=' + 'your_secret')
```

The text below is quoted from the blog post.

> This defense acts both as access control and authentication. The
>   listener URL you provide to DocuSign can include one or more query
>   parameters. DocuSign will include them during its POST request to your
>   listener.
>
> For access control, your listener will first check that the request
>   includes the expected query parameter and reject all requests that
>   don’t. For authentication, your listener will additionally check the
>   value of the query parameter. Remember that you can encode any values
>   for the name and value of the query parameter. For this example, we’re
>   using “pw” as the name of the query parameter.
>
> To use a pre-shared secret, just set the URL accordingly in the
>   Connect configuration. For example,
>   https://listener_url.example.com/listener?pw=secret
>
> Remember that the complete URL, including its query parameters, is
>   encrypted before it is sent across the internet. The URL and its query
>   parameters are visible in various logs and configuration screens,
>   including the Connect webhook configuration page.

Comment: Hi Lee - thanks for your response. The page you listed does not answer my question. I learned about Connect having Basic Auth from that page and so I have seen the solution you (and they) suggest - however this is a workaround, it isn't Basic Auth.

Comment: @MitchKent Hi, Mitch. As of now, the docusign doesn't support basic auth in their rest api. Please check the FAQ section in this post. I will include it in the answer. https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-connect-basic-authentication-support/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lee - I did look at the FAQ and each question refers specifically to the Connect platform, but "no support currently" was my best researched answer also.